# Why does ls sorting ignore non-alphanumeric characters?

Tags: ls, sort

When sorting file names, `ls` ignores characters like `-,_`. I expected it to use those characters in sorting as well.

An example:

```
touch a1 a2 a-1 a-2 a_1 a_2 a.1 a.2 a,1 a,2
```

Now display these files with `ls -1`:

```
a1
a_1
a-1
a,1
a.1
a2
a_2
a-2
a,2
a.2
```

What I expected was something like this:

```
a1
a2
a,1
a,2
a.1
a.2
a_1
a_2
a-1
a-2
```

i.e. I expected the non-alphanumeric characters to be taken into account when sorting.

Can anyone explain this behaviour? Is this behaviour mandated by a standard? Or is this due the encoding being UTF-8?

**Update:** It seems that this is related to UTF-8 sorting:

```
$ LC_COLLATE=C ls -1
a,1
a,2
a-1
a-2
a.1
a.2
a1
a2
a_1
a_2
```

Comment: UTF-8 and ASCII are identical if all you're using is the first 128 codepoints (which your example is). What happens if you do `LC_COLLATE=C ls`?

Comment: The problem is not that ASCII and UTF-8 are identical, it's rather that UTF-8 has its own collation (sorting) rules.

Comment: Yes, it's true  that `[_-,.]` are being grouped and somehow semi-ignored. I don't know exactly how or where such collation is defined, but it must be a collation issue, because simply, and only, changing the collation to **C** (via `LC_COLLATE=C ls -l`) is enough to give you the sort order you expected (assuming the `LC_ALL` is not overriding `LC_COLLATE`). This holds true for the entire range of characters in the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane... I've edited my answer to include an example script  which bears this out...

Comment: if you don't like how it works, you can create an alias and put it in your ~/.profile: alias ls='LC_COLLATE=C ls'</kbd>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the charset. Rather, it's the language that determines the collation order. The libc examines the language presented in `$LC_COLLATE`/`$LC_ALL`/`$LANG` and looks up its collation rules (e.g. `/usr/share/i18n/locales/*` for GLibC) and orders the text as directed.

Comment: FYI:  It's more complicated than this.  If one were to use ```strcoll``` for example, you would see that something like `aasa.c` would be sorted above `aas.c`.

Answer (score 14):

EDIT: Added test for data sorted with LC_COLLATE=C

---

The default collate sequence is treating those  "punctuation-type" characters as being of equal value.. `Use LC_COLLATE=C` to treat them in codepoint order ..

```
for i in 'a1' 'a_1' 'a-1' 'a,1' 'a.1' 'a2' 'a_2' 'a-2' 'a,2' 'a.2' ;do
  echo $i; 
done |LC_COLLATE=C sort
```

Output

```
a,1
a,2
a-1
a-2
a.1
a.2
a1
a2
a_1
a_2
```

---

The following code tests all *valid* UTF-8 chars in the Basic Multilingual Plane (except for *\x00* and *\x0a*; for simplicity)
It compares a file in a known (generated) ascending sequence, against that file randomly sorted and then sorted again with LC_COLLATE=C. The result shows that the **C** sequence is identical to the original generated sequence.

```
{ i=0 j=0 k=0 l=0
  for i in {0..9} {A..F} ;do
  for j in {0..9} {A..F} ;do
  for k in {0..9} {A..F} ;do
  for l in {0..9} {A..F} ;do
     (( 16#$i$j$k$l == 16#0000 )) && { printf '.' >&2; continue; }
     (( 16#$i$j$k$l == 16#000A )) && { printf '.' >&2; continue; }
     (( 16#$i$j$k$l >= 16#D800    && 
        16#$i$j$k$l <= 16#DFFF )) && { printf '.' >&2; continue; }
     (( 16#$i$j$k$l >= 16#FFFE )) && { printf '.' >&2; continue; }
     echo 0x"$i$j$k$l" |recode UTF-16BE/x4..UTF-8 || { echo "ERROR at codepoint $i$j$k$l " >&2; continue; } 
     echo 
  done
  done
  done; echo -n "$i$j$k$l " >&2
  done; echo >&2
} >listGen

             sort -R listGen    > listRandom
LC_COLLATE=C sort    listRandom > listCsort 

diff <(cat listGen;   echo "last line of listOrig " ) \
     <(cat listCsort; echo "last line of listCsort" )
echo 
cmp listGen listCsort; echo 'cmp $?='$?
```

Output:

```
63485c63485
< last line of listOrig 
---
> last line of listCsort

cmp $?=0
```

Comment: Where is that documented? Is that part of the Unicode standard?

Comment: Actually, they don't get the same value; those characters are simply ignored when sorting. If they were treated as having an equal value, the sorting order `a_1 a2 a_2` would be impossible.

Comment: +1 for your hard work and sample code. After many hours sorting directory names with punctuation to match the way `tree` does it I think there is more to the story such as punctuation being removed from comparison strings or something like that. I can say the `/` character has to be set as the lowest character in the collating sequence no matter what else.

Answer (score 4):

I am having exactly the same issue with Debian's default sort options, for me it's a comma that it's ignoring and that's preventing me from sorting CSV data effectively causing havoc in my AI.

The solution is, instead of using `sort` on it's own, that i need to force sort out of the default behaviour which seems to be `-d, --dictionary-order`.

Running the command:

```
sort -V
```

Fixes my problem and considers commas.

Comment: You might want to look at using the option ```-t,``` (or ```--field-separator ,```) which will then sort on the values of the fields (up to a point - embedded commas in data fields will throw it off). Surely someone, somewhere has written a program that will decode the CSV, sort records, then spit them out again?

Answer (score 0):

just a comment... i ve a big deal with my collation (es_AR.utf8) cos i cannot use 'C' because de accents and worst of all is that the problem appears in the db postgresql too doing that the sentence between '10' and '10.1' include (it's an example) the value '100' which i don't expect .. i guess i have to use the collation in each query .. SELECT '100' BETWEEN '10' AND '10.Z' shows true but SELECT '100' BETWEEN '10' AND '10.Z' COLLATE "C" shows 'false' which is correct (in my mind)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/424632)