# Why does sort ignore dollar ($) at beginning of line?

Tags: sort

I just got aware that `sort` seems to ignore dollar characters at the beginning of the line.
Why is that?
Example:

```
user@host:~$ cat 5.txt
$_a
_b
$_c
user@host:~$ sort 5.txt
$_a
_b
$_c
```

I have Debian 9.2 Stretch.

Comment: I didn't immediately find https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326936/why-does-this-sort-ignore-the-character-prefix Once I had found it, I would have liked to add a comment with search string "dollar", to help finding it. I couldn't (and still can't) add a comment, because I don't have 50 reputation...

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer here:

[Why does this sort ignore the +/- character prefix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326936/why-does-this-sort-ignore-the-character-prefix)

`sort` works as expected with

```
LC_COLLATE=C sort 5.txt
```