# How to make alphabetical sorting work with whitespace?

Tags: linux, ls, filenames, nautilus

I am on Ubuntu 19.04

ls outputs the following, and this is how it appears in nautilus as well

```
Arca - Arca
Arcade Fire - Funeral
Arca - Mutant
```

Obviously, this should be as below. Is it possible to make it so in the entire OS?

```
Arca - Arca
Arca - Mutant
Arcade Fire - Funeral
```

Comment: Probably related: [Besides the non-C locale, what else is messing up my sort?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/346423/65304)