# Windows-like LC_COLLATE?

Tags: bash, gnome, windows, locale

One of the most infuriating things that causes me much frustration when I am using Linux is the completely assinine way that files get sorted when sorting by name. This is compounded by the output of `ls -l` producing a different sort order than, say, Nautilus.

Is there a simple way to get Windows-like collation in Linux so I can stop beating my head against the wall?

**Symbols > Numbers > Letters** (modified letters such as `o-umlaut` just count as `o`)

This has been an open issue on the GNOME bug tracker for about 12 years or so now and I assume this will never be fixed properly, so perhaps there is a work around I can do?

Comment: Sounds like you want the C locale rather then a language/country specific one.

Comment: I've looked into that but from what I've read, both C and POSIX locales aren't quite right. Perhaps I misread?

Comment: Oh ok. Out of interest which is "wrong": Nautilus or `ls`?

Comment: Nautilus is the wrong one. Nautilus ignores prepended symbols so `_bbb` will show up after `aaa` instead of before.

Comment: After doing some more digging, I found that WINE has implemented this sort order for their purposes here: https://github.com/aidfarh/wine/blob/master/dlls/shlwapi/string.c#L2219-L2285

Comment: Also here is microsoft's definition of their own function: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strcmplogicalw

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471442/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39827/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35469/ .