# Windows explorer natural order sort order

Tags: sort

I am kinda ingrained with the Windows sort order in my head.  Unfortunately Windows doesn't really allow for an easy way to change it.

Is there a way to emulate such sort order using unix tools?

An example if each is a file name

```
{"Ie4 01", "Ie4!01", "Ie4_01", "Ie4_128", "Ie5", "Ie6", "Ie401sp2","Ie501sp2"}
```

correct sort order

```
Ie4 01
Ie4!01
Ie4_01
Ie4_128
Ie5
Ie6
Ie401sp2
Ie501sp2
```

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35469/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39827/ .

Comment: Similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/467638/windows-like-lc-collate

Comment: In what environment are you looking for this? `ls`? A GUI file browser?

Comment: @JeffSchaller ls but it was mean to be a generalized question for sure.

Comment: @JeffSchaller oh environment bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU sort's version sort (`-V`) seems to provide that output:

```
~ printf "%s\n" "Ie5" "Ie6" "Ie4 01" 'Ie4!01' "Ie4_01" "Ie4_128" "Ie401sp2" "Ie501sp2" |
  sort -V
Ie4 01
Ie4!01
Ie4_01
Ie4_128
Ie5
Ie6
Ie401sp2
Ie501sp2
```

Comment: I prefer it with out the > so its copy and pastable.  thank you in practicality folders seem to me folders are listed 1st so I would just need to concat the 2 separated sorted lists.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is wanting to separate folders and files like Windows does, you can do this:

```
ls -d */ -1 | sort -V
ls -p | grep -v / | sort -V
```

Comment: If this was for `ls`, a new enough GNU `ls` should also support version sorting (`-v` or `--sort=version`)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not particular about the ordering of the special characters, then `zsh`'s numeric sorting glob qualifier gets close:

## Setup

```
$ touch "Ie5" "Ie6" "Ie4 01" 'Ie4!01' "Ie4_01" "Ie4_128" "Ie401sp2" "Ie501sp2"
$ mkdir Foo Quux Ie7bar
```

## zsh only

```
$ print -l *(n/) *(n^/)
Foo
Ie7bar
Quux
Ie4 01
Ie4_01
Ie4!01
Ie4_128
Ie5
Ie6
Ie401sp2
Ie501sp2
```

## with ls

```
$ ls -1df *(n/) *(n^/)
Foo
Ie7bar
Quux
Ie4 01
Ie4_01
Ie4!01
Ie4_128
Ie5
Ie6
Ie401sp2
Ie501sp2
```

The flags to `ls` are:

- force single-column output (`-1`) -- simply for ease of viewing
- do not descend into directories (`-d`)
- do not sort the incoming list (`-f` or `-U`)

The zsh glob qualifiers say:

- `*(n/)` - expand to the list of directories `/`, ordered numerically
- `*(n^/)` - expand to the list of items that are *not* `^` directories, ordered numerically

I mention a zsh solution just because you can then manipulate the results more easily, without having to worry about quoting filenames or delimiting them with nulls. For example:

```
$ mine=( *(/n) *(n^/) )
$ for file in "${mine[@]}"; do print -l "$file"; done
Foo
Ie7bar
Quux
Ie4 01
Ie4_01
Ie4!01
Ie4_128
Ie5
Ie6
Ie401sp2
Ie501sp2
$ print -l "${mine[-1]}"
Ie501sp2
```